# Sort vector of class in c++

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

I am having some trouble with the sort function... here is my code:

```
class Parola {
public:
    string s;
    int repetition;
    bool operator()(const Parola *x, const Parola *y) {
        return x->repetition > y->repetition;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ...
    vector<Parola> p;
    ...
    some insertions here
    ...
    sort(p.begin(), p.end(), Parola());
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Why I can't compile this without errors?
Thanks a lot!

PS: I will show you only the first three lines of over fifty of errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h: In function 'const _Tp& std::__median(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _Tp = Parola, _Compare = Parola]':
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2795:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Parola*, std::vector<Parola, std::allocator<Parola> > >, _Size = long int, _Compare = Parola]'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:2866:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Parola*, std::vector<Parola, std::allocator<Parola> > >, _Compare = Parola]'
```

Comment: You're overriding the functional operator. You want to override operator <. Furthermore, change the param (single) to be a const reference, and the operator itself should be const as well.

Comment: What steps did you try to resolve it yourself?

Comment: It's quite unorthodox to use `Parola` as both the item being compared and a comparator, but I guess that's an acceptable practice.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: acceptable to the compiler (if `operator()` were fixed to take `const Parola&`). Maybe not to your colleagues :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I agree, it took me a while to see what's going on there, and how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: my guess is that it isn't *supposed* to work like that at all. The questioner is "quite new at C++", and most likely took a wrong turn trying to get something that works at all, rather than trying to do something obscure. Maybe doesn't realise that the default sort is via `std::less` and hence `operator<` is sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Giving the OP some options to choose from: (note: not exhaustive)

## Option 1: Internal operator <()

```
class Parola {
public:
    string s;
    int repetition;
    bool operator<(const Parola& x) const  
    {
        return repetition < x.repetition;
    }
}
```

called using the default std::less<> template.

```
sort(p.begin(), p.end());
```

## Option 2: Internal Functional operator()():

```
class Parola {
public:
    string s;
    int repetition;
    bool operator()(const Parola& x, const Parola& y) const  
    {
        return x.repetition < y.repetition;
    }
}
```

called with optional comparison object, as dasblinken pointed out, odd, but works:

```
std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(), Parola());
```

## Option 3: External operator <()

```
bool operator <(const Parola& x, const Parola& y)
{
    x.repetition < y.repetition;
}
```

This, like (1), uses the default std::less<> comparator, but requires that the external operator also be a friend of class Parola to have access to the private data members if declared as such. Its use is the same as (1).

## Option 4: External Functor

```
class CompareParola
{
public:
   bool operator ()(const Parola& x, const Parola& y) const
   {
      return x.repetition < right.repetition;
   }
};
```

And used by:

```
std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(), CompareParola());
```

Like (3), the CompareParola class must be friended to Parola if the members being accessed are private:

## Option 5: External Function

```
bool ParolaLess(const Parola& x, const Parola& y)
{
    return x.repetition < y.repetition;
}
```

Similar to an external operator or external functional class, this also requires being friended to the object class to gain access to the private members. Invoked like such:

```
std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(), ParolaLess);
```

## Option 6: Static Class Function

```
class Parola {
public:
    string s;
    int repetition;

    static bool Less(const Parola& x, const Parola& y)  
    {
        return x.repetition < y.repetition;
    }
};
```

This is often under-utilized, and has the very nice attribute of having access to all the object member variables, including private ones (obviously, its defined with the class). You can use this by doing:

```
std::sort(p.begin(), p.end(), Parola::Less)
```

Note that this, like (1) and (2), keeps everything in the class.

Of all of these I prefer (1) for its simplicity, and (4) for its independence, but everyone has their tastes. There are times that (5) or (6) really comes in handy (and I'm a personal fan of (6)).

If you can think of any more and have the rep to edit it, kindly update this as needed. Please do try to make them at least somewhat useful =P

Comment: Small error in option 3: if it is a free function then you have one ``const`` too many.

Comment: Thanks, Juan. got it fixed up. thx for the proof-read as well.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! There are some options more CPU efficient than others (may be due to inline)?

Comment: More or less, yes. you'll likely find the functions perform better, as there is no construction involved. Of all of these (and I've not tested them personally) I would think (2) would perform the *worst*.

Answer (score 6):

Your comparator takes pointers, but the vector holds `Parola` instances. You need to change that. But the easiest would be to implement a less-than comparison operator.

```
class Parola {
public:
    string s;
    int repetition;
};

bool operator<(const Parola& x, const Parola& y) {
    return x.repetition < y.repetition;
}
```

Then you can call `sort` without a 3rd argument:

```
sort(p.begin(), p.end());
```

Comment: Small problem with the `operator<`: It is defined as a member function here, so it will take `this`, `x` and `y` as arguments, which does not work to well...

Comment: @WhozCraig: I think an `operator<()` taking three objects isn't worth considering the `const` on all three arguments :)

Comment: if using the default std::less<>, there should only be one argument (a const Parola&) and the comparison should eval against *this, so yeah, Juan, change that.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Personally I would go with the non member (friend) function variant using 2 arguments.

Comment: @DietmarKühl My god I'm worthless without my coffee on Mondays. Upvoted your answer Dieter, as of all of these its the best by far. option #3 isn't there, but as Grizz said, its a preference.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well, the comparator is probably a better option than passing a pointer to a function: The function pointer often doesn't get inlined while the structure's function call operator is! Also, with all members (incorrectly, probably) being public, there is no need to use a friend.

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate problem is that your comparison operator doesn't get passed `Parola const*` objects but `Parola const&` objects: the iterators get dereferenced to get a value which is actually compared.

The next problem is that you probably shouldn't try to bundle your comparison object into your actual objects: the comparison object doesn't really behave like a `Parola` object. You want to have a separate comparator which is then used with `std::sort()`:

```
sturct ParolaCompare {
    bool operator()(Parola const& p0, Parola const& p1) const {
        // return something defining a strict weak order on Parola objects
    }
};
// ...
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ParolaCompare());
```

Alternatively, you can define a suitable `operator<()` for your `Parola` objects:

```
bool operator< (Parola const& p0, Parola const& p1) {
    // again, a strict weak order on Parola objects
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the operator take const references instead of pointers. I.e.

```
bool operator()(const Parola &x, const Parola &y) { 
    return x.repetition > y.repetition; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally when-ever you have an object that you want the STL to sort for you, either using the sort method, or putting it in a std::set, you need a operator< method.

Hence it's best to make it a member of the class. The signature of that method should be something like:
bool operator<(const Parola& left, const Parola& right)

How you implement it is dependent on your class itself.

Comment: Did someone add a functional operator to compare individual elements in an std::vector<> while I wasn't paying attention? I must have missed.. something.